# Extract IP from netstat output

Tags: shell, awk, netstat

The netstat output contains thing like...

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80       221.126.149.99:51973    ESTABLISHED 23879/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80        66.249.68.154:40883     ESTABLISHED 23899/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80       66.249.68.81:41200      ESTABLISHED 23892/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80       66.249.67.121:59355     ESTABLISHED 23905/apache2
tcp        0   4465 0.0.0.0:80       110.75.175.27:48139     ESTABLISHED 23901/apache2
```

I use this commands

```
netstat -anpt|grep apache2 |grep ESTABLISHED | awk -F "[ :]" '{print $4}'
```

I was not able to get the IP, any hints?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will return a list of unique IP address you're connected too:

```
netstat -anpt | grep apache2 |grep ESTABLISHED | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u
```

Well I think I need to change my glasses also =P

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
netstat -anpt|awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ :]+"};/ESTABLISHED/ && /apache/{print $6}'
```

For some reason **I** am counting 6 fields, while everybody else is counting 4 ... Should I buy new glasses? :)

HTH!

Comment: You're not the only one.  I'd recommend moving the grep patterns inside awk.

Comment: @glenn jackman Agree. Edited. Sometimes, in the well formed questions, when the OP posts his solution, I feel it's better to modify the minimum possible, because it makes the bug easier to understand. May be I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

You're really close.  You just need to change your field separator regular expression so that it's not considering a single whitespace or colon as the field separator:

```
netstat -anpt|grep apache2 |grep ESTABLISHED | awk -F "[ :]*" '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
netstat -anpt | awk '/apache2/&&/ESTABLISHED/{sub(/:*/,"",$4);print $4} '
```

Comment: The awk action should be: `{sub(/:.*/,"",$5);print $5}`

Comment: why is it $5? I am not using any FS but the default

Comment: It used to be $4, but went up to $5. Inflated code.

Answer (score -1):

```
 netstat -ant | grep 80 | wc -l
```

Comment: This will count how many 80 listed in the output of 'netstat -ant' command, which is way inaccurate.